# Displaying of form not as per the code showing four input field instead of Two

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form code with two input field.But this form is sowing four input field as shown in the picture here the second input drop down is depending upon the first input value.Why this form is displaying eratic
[It is appearing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3W6X.jpg) 
Generate Receipt

```
    <form>
    
<label align="center "Style="font-size:14px;color:black;text-align:center;font-weight:heavy;"> UIN</label>
    
<select name="uin" id="uin">
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT uin from  tblstationerystock group by uin order by uin asc";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{  ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?></option>
 <?php }} ?>
</select>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label> ORDER DATE<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="orderdate" id="orderdate" value=""; >

</select>
</div>
    
    
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "eratic"? Do you want the inputs to be the same size?

Comment: @Dr.Tenma i have code for two input but it is showing for input in display

Comment: Please include your CSS.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma I am not using css for this particular code